# Postgresql-Finding duplicate lines details

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

The following query returns me some lines :

```
SELECT   COUNT(*) AS Dup, virtual_switch_id, slot_number, port_number
FROM     switch_port
GROUP BY virtual_switch_id, slot_number, port_number
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1

dup virtual_switch_id   slot_number port_number
2   47                  0           5
2   46                  0           5
2   26                  1           22
2   46                  0           2
```

That's exactly what I first wanted, but I need to have further information.
Is it possible to have another values (which are not part of the duplicates) ?

Each duplicate line (with 3 fields tested) has a unique id (primary key) in the switch_port table (and other interesting fields) and each virtual_switch_id has a name in another table, called switch_conf.

So I want to have some results like that (only where my first three fields are duplicated) :

```
virtual_switch_id   slot_number port_number id  value1 switch_conf.name
47                  0           5           0   val1   sw1 
47                  0           5           1   val2   sw1
26                  1           22          2   val1   sw2
26                  1           22          8   val4   sw2
26                  1           22          12  val1   sw2
```

In order to select what are the duplicates entries I must delete.

Tried some 'join' with no results (cartesian product instead...). I think that GROUP BY is not the right solution...

Any clues/answsers appreciated.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You just want to delete you duplicate records?

Comment: I want to keep only a record, manually deleting duplicates, found when having some values...

Comment: Please add some sample data **to your question** and explain your expected output more detailed. In that case I did not understand want you want to retrieve

Comment: I want to have an output like the second provided in the initial question. With this output, I can choose which 'id' I must delete (e.g : the '1' of the duplicate line 47,0,5 because the value of 'value1' field is not correct for me).

Comment: I just want have output when having duplicates lines with the same values of the first 3 fields. Otherwise, I've thousands of results (not compatible with human brain !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`COUNT()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), which adds a column with a row count to each element of a group (= partition). Afterwards you can select all records with row count >= 2:

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY virtual_switch_id, slot_number, port_number)
        FROM switch_port
    ) s
    WHERE count >= 2
```

Comment: No, I want more information to select which row I delete (must investigate before a manual deletion).

Comment: Does not work as expected : output only one line among the duplicates, I want to have both to choose which one is to be deleted.

Comment: Changed row_number into count. Should now show all groups with duplicates.

Comment: just added some fields and tables to gather more information (with WHERE clause completion to join)